# button below recyclerview disappear

Tags: button, android-recyclerview

here is my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.esraabalbaa.graduationproject.CartActivity">`enter code here <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#009688"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gotoback"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cart"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/selecteditemcounter"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mycartrecycler"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/checkoutsummary"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Checkout"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>
```

im displaying a button below the recyclerview, button dont appear when i first open the activity and it  does appear only when i delet an item from the recyclerview so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using layout weights:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight=".90" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addToDo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:text="Add Item" />

</LinearLayout>
```